# How to make Telegram Bot get User info from mention

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

I just started studying the Telegram Bot API to learn how to program a Bot via Java.
I don't understand how the bot can recognize a user mentioned via `@<username>` and get info about him.

For example, suppose I want my bot to be able to count and store how many times a user is mentioned into a group. What he needs is the tagged user's `id`.

I can parse incoming messages to detect entities using `update.getMessage().getEntities()` then get the type of entity using `MessageEntity.getType()`. Now, if I understood, there are two types of mention: `mention` for mentions made trough `@<username>`, and `text_mention` for mentions made to users who have no username.
Here come the problems, because I would expect a bot to be able to retrive more info about a user with username, since it's editable but unique, than about a user without username, since he is 'tagged' using the name he is saved with in the contact list of the sender.
Instead, only `text_mention` type `MessageEntity` object contains `User` object, from which i can get user's `id`, as i read in [Telegram Bot API documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#messageentity). From `mention` type `MessageEntity` object i can just get the username itself as it is the text, but it is not enough because it can be changed.

So my first question is: why? I really don't understand why `text_mention` should carry info about tagged user while `mention` should not.

Then the main question is: how can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now there is **NO** proper way to do it.

For such feature you can user [TdLib](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib). Here are [Java examples](https://github.com/tdlib/td/tree/master/example/java)

If user's are in group, where they were mentioned, you can use such methods to get list of user's and find by username:

```
//@description  Return recently joined users in reverse chronological order 
channelParticipantsRecent = ChannelParticipantsFilter;

//@description  Return privileged participants  
channelParticipantsAdmins = ChannelParticipantsFilter;

//@description  Return kicked from the channel  
channelParticipantsKicked = ChannelParticipantsFilter;

//@description  Return bots in the channel  
channelParticipantsBots = ChannelParticipantsFilter;
```